# Entity Framework EntityState and SaveChanges behaviour without changes

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Regarding Entity Framework states, specifically when it comes to updating records with a `SaveChanges` call, I know it'll only update records that have a modified `EntityState` (ignoring add/delete for now)

My question is how is this tracked and how does it handle assignments with unchanged values?

I'm trying to work out if

```
if (value1.Text != table.value1) { table.value1 = value1.Text; }
```

is necessary to stop superfluous updates or if I can get away with:

```
table.value1 = value1.Text;
```

or will that set the state to a 'modified' flag on the record, even if the value is the same?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj556205,

> When using most POCO entities the determination of how an entity has
>   changed (and therefore which updates need to be sent to the database)
>   is handled by the Detect Changes algorithm. Detect Changes works by
>   detecting the differences between the current property values of the
>   entity and the original property values that are stored in a snapshot
>   when the entity was queried or attached.

Entity Framework automatically run the above **Detect Changes** when calling to DbContext.SaveChanges. And EF actually determine changes by comparing current value and original value to